# Edit .blend file's Text only

Tags: edit, blender

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73614

I have downloaded this and want to use my own text on it using Blender (or another program). It is not used for commercial purpose. When I open it, I get no option to edit text. I tried edit external and GIMP which failed.

Answer (score 1):

the .blend file is binary and can only be opened inside of Blender, When you create text objects they are displayed as objects inside blender. You should be able to find the object by using the object browser section inside blender and changing it there. You may have to recreate the text object depending on how the author did the original.